# Type or interface for multiple cases

Tags: typescript

I have a situation where I'm creating a state that can potentially take in an empty object `{}`, an object that has only one property of `{paymentMethod: string}` or an object that can only have two properties of `{ cardBrand: string, cardLastThreeDigits: string }`.

I've tried a few different ways, but I can't seem to get this to work, the closest I've come would be:

```
    const [selectedPaymentMethod, setSelectedPaymentMethod] = useState<
        Card | (Record<any, never> & { paymentMethod?: string })
    >({});
```

So naturally, after that I tried doing this:

```
export type SelectedPaymentMethodTypes = Card | (Record<any, never> & { paymentMethod?: string });
```

`Card` being the the `{ cardBrand: string, cardLastThreeDigits: string }` object, `Record<any, never>` being used as the empty object, and `& { paymentMethod?: string })` trying to extend the empty object in case non of those two match.

Is there any way of making something like this happen in an interface or type so that it could be exported and used everywhere? Without doing `{} as` for example everywhere.

Just returned with what I think could be a example of this failing [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJygE2QbwFDLIIaYBCUcImAXMgM5hSgDmANAUSQDJwMAqACygQIAEWDNgYOrQZMQzPAF88eUJFiIUAeTADo2gEYArCAjC4OABzgBPALYRwAWQh6A9jXqMWy1QgAbXjpkAAU7R3B0LEtCYixRODA4WmjsAB9kACUzdywAHjkWVmRKWwA%20ZEzdfSgjU3NVOPcQOQBXczyACnjMROTUkirs3IKihRKyyuq9AxMzMABKWMJkPWA6ADpe-rhkAF5OBKS4AG4OFQ46NzTdrpAIAHdbk8GYzJyEPMxCnwnSkAVYY1OYNJYrQjCMBtKAgNYCDbbEi7c6EFSXL6tCy9A7IB6PMIRJxgNJdHBKRbnPC9TbXEnIk5ko5kChUWgAcgAagBJADKAEF2SVejx%20EIROJJNIOQBGABMAGYACzs5AUqmYhi4ZnkSiYYUM5Jq3E0nYnDUkWk3Q1wJk2BzE1weLzszAQALAABu0FsqvV-haWpwyHtkTAToEnmNh1NNotWCt9OOyTJ-upgfcAQgmwC7mYPUtZuSlKAA).

Comment: What about a union: `Record<never, never> | { paymentMethod: string } | { cardBrand: string; cardLastThreeDigits: string }` and maybe having type guards to distinguish between them?

Comment: hey Kelly, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I don't really understand the difference, `Record<never, never> | { paymentMethod: string } | { cardBrand: string; cardLastThreeDigits: string }` would translate to `Record<never, never> | { paymentMethod: string } | Card`, which is basically the same thing as `Card | (Record<any, never> & { paymentMethod?: string })`. But I did also test your suggestion, and is still fails.

Comment: Oh yeah that union wouldn't do much now would it - what about a discriminated union? Even one that does not reflect the types at runtime but only exist for the purpose of discriminating constituents of the union?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally others could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mZGkEW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Does this question depend on react? If so you might want to tag it as such; if not, please consider removing `useState()` or any such dependency from your example code

Comment: Hello @jcalz, this question does not depend on react, it is specific to the case were you might export a method that takes 1 parameter that can be, either a empty object, a object with certain keys, or a object with completele different keys. Sets the data in any variable, variable that can accept the same kind of data that I've just mentioned, and then pass it along to some destructuring that would then destructure something like this `{cardBrand, cardLastThreeDigits, paymentMethod}`. I will get to work on building a playground for this as soon as I get home! Thank you

Comment: Note that the example code should be in plaintext in the question itself; a playground link is a great supplement but not a substitute for having a self-contained issue in the post.